# HTTPS on IP address and not on domain name?

Tags: ssl, https, hosting

It looks like HTTPS certificate for an IP address and not for domain name is possible.

My goal is to have an HTTPS on an IP address
ex: https://XX.YY.WW.ZZ

However I cannot find any company that provides such service: any advice ?

Comment: Spend $7 on a domain and be done with it. While technologically possible, no major SSL vendor I'm aware of will sell you one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043617/is-it-possible-to-have-ssl-certificate-for-ip-address-not-domain-name

Answer (score 6):

There is a number of reasons why what you are asking for is a bad idea and why you are unlikely to acquire such a certificate.

- The only parties who can legitimately request such a certificate are those who actually have their own IP range. If you only have a single IP allocated from your ISP, that IP address still belongs to your ISP. A CA cannot know how long that IP address would be assigned to you, so they cannot legitimately issue a certificate.
- Using IP addresses in URLs is not a good practice and will break your site for a percentage of users. In particular there are users whose only way to access an IPv4-only server is through NAT64. Such users will never be able to access a URL with an IPv4 address.
- A certificate only certifies that you are legitimately allowed to serve the domain in the certificate. It is still the user's responsibility to ensure they are accessing the domain they expected to. With your scheme that means the users have to memorise the IP addresses and recognise if an incorrect IP address shows up in the URL.
- Due to an IP address having the most significant part first and a domain name having the most significant part last, there is a significant risk of code for validating origin of content having bugs that only apply to URLs with IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

GlobalSign's OrganizationSSL certificate includes support for public IP addresses: https://www.globalsign.com/en/ssl/organization-ssl/

Note that not only must this be a public IP address, but it also must be one that you *own* (as per [RIPE](https://apps.db.ripe.net/search/query.html))